# Is it possible to set multiple internal relations in one column in sql?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I would like to set a column in one of my tables to be internally related to three different primary keys. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

These 3 primary keys are related to each other; a primary key is a foreign key to another table and this table's primary key is also a foreign key to another table. I would like to use these 3 primary keys as foreign keys to many tables. Since these 3 are related I think it would be more space-efficient if I just put either one of these 3 primary keys and query the rest for display. what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to set a column in one of my tables to be internally
>   related to three different primary keys. Is it possible?

No. That would not make any sense in a relational model.

You need to create 3 separate columns to relate to 3 different table's primary keys.